# Non-ascii character highlight in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

I have been using Sublime for a few months with great enjoyment until yesterday when something was corrupted and I needed to reinstall.

Since I thought I had all the packages I used memorized, I didn't keep a backup and did a full uninstall/reinstall of the app and the application support folder.

One of the features I really liked was that if I pasted in copy from another source, like Word, all the characters like curly quotes, etc. would be highlighted in hot pink.

This is no longer working and I believe it must've been a package I installed and didn't realize it. It saves a lot of time if you have to convert text to HTML content.

Does anyone know what package that is or how to get that behavior back in ST2?

I have been all over Google and cannot figure out how this was working. My mistake for throwing my settings/packages away.

Comment: ProTip: store your application's data folder in Dropbox (or w/ever) and symlink it to where app expects it to be.

Comment: Not sure that would've helped in this case, but that is a good suggestion.

Comment: [It would](https://www.dropbox.com/help/296/en); also helps with keeping config consistent between multiple machines. `Application Support` sounds like you are an OS X user, what about Time Machine, maybe it has an older copy? If not, maybe [this page](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/highlight) could help.

Comment: No luck, but I may run across it in the future. I am taking your advice on the Dropbox suggestion. That is a good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I recently wrote a plugin dedicated to this exact problem: highlighting non-ascii characters.
https://github.com/TuureKaunisto/highlight-dodgy-chars

The plugin works on a whitelist principle: all non-ascii characters that are not whitelisted in the settings get highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

I think the package you're after is [Highlighter](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Highlighter). It highlights a few unicode characters in that hot pink you referred to. You can add more matches via settings ([example](https://github.com/bluegray/Highlighter/blob/master/highlighter.sublime-settings)).