# Simple PHP If Statement error

Tags: php

I have a very simple IF statement...

```
if ($key == "listingURL" or 
     $key == "interiorColor" or 
     $key == "engine" or 
     $key == "transmission" or 
     $key == "stockNumber" or 
     $key == "VIN") {
          // Do thing
}
```

But I'm receiving an error...

> [23-Apr-2015 13:12:01 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected
>   T_VARIABLE in xxx on line xxx

Which is this line...

```
 $key == "stockNumber" or
```

Is there a limit to the maximum amount of OR's, or am I missing something staring me right in the face?

Comment: One suggestion: Use in_array or something else to check a value of a variable against multiple values: $values = array( 'listingURL', 'interiorColor'); if ( in_array( $key, $values) ) { //do stuff

Comment: Or may be you can use || in place of or

Comment: Use an hexeditor. There's a stray BOM in there `<FEFF>`.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia, tried earlier but no difference!

Comment: @SoWizardly an additional edit was made to my answer in regards to plugins

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> *"Is there a limit to the maximum amount of OR's, or am I missing something staring me right in the face?"*

No there isn't. The reason is because you have a hidden character:

```
$key == "transmission" or ? <= right there
```

[image]

Which is `&#65279;`

Being a Unicode [ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) character.

Rewrite:

```
if ($key == "listingURL" or 
     $key == "interiorColor" or 
     $key == "engine" or 
     $key == "transmission" or
     $key == "stockNumber" or 
     $key == "VIN") {
          // Do thing
}
```

**Sidenotes:**

As from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824738/simple-php-if-statement-error#comment47776031_29824803):

> I'll confirm this as the correct answer as soon as the time limit is up! Thank you so much for the help. I use Sublime Text 3, **is there some easy way to detect these hidden characters?** –  SoWizardly 19 mins ago

For [`Notepad++`](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)  there is a plugin called: `HEX-Editor`.

You can download it via: Extensions -> Plugin Manager -> Available. Just check the combo box for `HEX-Editor` and click install. After this you can change your file view to hexadecimal.

For [`Sublime Text`](http://www.sublimetext.com/) there is also a [plugin](https://github.com/facelessuser/HexViewer), which does the same.

Comment: I'll confirm this as the correct answer as soon as the time limit is up! Thank you so much for the help. I use Sublime Text 3, is there some easy way to detect these hidden characters?

Comment: @SoWizardly Well, I use Notepad++ and that came up as an Unicode. I have never used Sublime, but there's probably an viewing option in it.

Comment: Nice catch. EDIT: NVM, just saw you use a different text editor. That may just be the case :)

Comment: @BeatAlex strangely enough, I started off with regular Notepad, noticed the little square at the end of the line, slapped into Notepad++ and also my HTML page editor to confirm.

Comment: wow, couldn't have checked this +1, does anyone know how to do this in sublime? i'd like to know it as well. anyway, great catch Fred.

Comment: @Ghost Thanks Ghost. Good question though. I never used it so I can't say unless I researched it.

Comment: @SoWizardly I found this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/20356784/ and https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Unicode%20Character%20Highlighter and http://stackoverflow.com/a/20999477/ - there were more links while Googling "how to detect unicode characters  with sublime". I hope it helps.

Comment: @Ghost I made an edit to my answer under Sidenotes about plugins. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah thanks for that, never would have checked for these kinds of error lol :D i'd just look at the question as it is.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for all your help! I was having some issues getting a .csv file importer to work, and it looks like that character came from me copy+pasting...which lead me to realize that's what was causing the problem...I ended up finding a nice PHP script that strips these characters from strings, and now everything works as intended!

Comment: @SoWizardly You're very much welcome. I'm glad you were able to find the root of the problem and to solve it as you said, with the script you found. *Cheers*

Comment: There is no hidden char in phpstorm or probably auto remove?

Comment: @Nucleo1985 That I couldn't say, I've never used phpstorm.

Comment: The same person who just downvoted this answer, also downvoted http://stackoverflow.com/a/18219669/1415724 and suspect a certain someone who couldn't take the fact that his answer was wrong. You have a lot of nerve.

Answer (score 2):

When i copy in other editor i get this 
 remove it near stock number ? <=

```
if ($key == "listingURL" or 
     $key == "interiorColor" or 
     $key == "engine" or 
     $key == "transmission" or 
     $key == "stockNumber" or ? <=
     $key == "VIN") {
          // Do thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$arr = array("listingURL","interiorColor","engine","transmission","stockNumber","VIN");
if(in_array($key, $arr))
{
   // do something 
}
```

this is much more effective way of doing things

Answer (score 0):

Copy of comment:
One suggestion: Use in_array or something else to check a value of a variable against multiple values:

```
$values = array( 'listingURL', 'interiorColor');
if ( in_array( $key, $values) ) { //do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Unwanted characters from `$key == "transmission" or ? <=`

```
? <=` This causes the problem
```